# Why is there an inconsistency in the definitions of the retrace?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, papers, retrace

In Section 4.3 of the paper [Learning by Playing - Solving Sparse Reward Tasks from Scratch](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.10567), the authors define Retrace as
$$
Q^{ret}=\sum_{j=i}^\infty\left(\gamma^{j-i}\prod_{k=i}^jc_k\right)[r(s_j,a_j)+\delta_Q(s_i,s_j)],\\
\delta_Q(s_i,s_j)=\mathbb E_{\pi_{\theta'}(a|s)}[Q^\pi(s_i,\cdot;\phi')]-Q^\pi(s_j,a_j;\phi')\\
c_k=\min\left(1,{\pi_{\theta'}(a_k|s_k)\over b(a_k|s_k)}\right)
$$
where I omit $\mathcal T$ for simplicity.
I'm quite confused about the definition of $Q^{ret}$, which seems not consistent with Retrace defined in [Safe and efﬁcient off-policy reinforcement learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.02647):

$$
\mathcal RQ(x,a):=Q(x,a)+\mathbb E_\mu[\sum_{t\ge0}\gamma^t\left(\prod_{s=1}^tc_s\right)(r_t+\gamma\mathbb E_\pi Q(x_{t+1},\cdot)-Q(x_t,a_t)]
$$

What should I make of $Q^{ret}$ in the first paper?